# Sequential feature selection stopping condition

Tags: feature-selection, optimization

When using sequential feature selection approach, say forward feature selection, I want to stop adding new features when the improvement in model scores is smaller than a certain level. Is there a standard criteria being used in this context as a stopping condition?

It reminds me of the case of using the elbow method in order to choose an optimal number of clusters. Are BIC/AIC relevant in the current problem? are there other methods?

I also looked at the scikit-learn implementation for sequential feature selection, and they don't support a stopping criteria which is based on the actual data, but require a predefined number of features to select, which for my understanding can result with either loss of valuable information / overfit...